# then not waiting for Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have this function using fetch

```
export async function login(email, password) {
  let url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
  url.search = new URLSearchParams({
    t: "login",
    email: email,
    password: password
  });

  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: new Headers()
  })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

And the function that's supposed to call it and handle the result is this

```
handleSubmit() {
    login(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(r => {
      console.log(r);
      if (String(r) === "true") this.props.updatePath("/main");
      else this.setState({ current: 1 });
    });
  }
```

I'm new to javascript, and I'm still a bit confused with async thing.
In the console, the log from the second comes before the log from the first function, so I'm assuming it's not waiting for it to function.

The log on the first function spits out the correct result, I just can't get it to the other side.

I was using axios at first (had some problems it with) and this approch worked. Is there something different about fetch that stops this from working?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to return the promise from `login()` -- `return fetch(u ...` Or you should just use async/await and don't use all the `then()` calls in login. Just return your awaited value.

Comment: I think you should put `await` behind the `fetch` call in your `login` function or, return it directly and don't use the `async` keyword

Comment: Upvoting Eddie and I would go with the first part of the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The Promise that comes from calling an `async` function resolves when that function returns. `login` internally doesn't await anything (that's probably a mistake). It returns before the internal `fetch` resolves. So while that fetch is in flight, your `then` callback in `handleSubmit` runs. Later the `fetch` initiated in `login` finishes and logs the actual response.

I would have you try writing `login` like this:

```
export async function login(email, password) {
  let url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
  url.search = new URLSearchParams({
    t: "login",
    email: email,
    password: password
  });

  try {
    let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: new Headers()
    });
    response = await response.text();
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    // original code had this issue where it doesn't reject on error nor resolve to anything useful
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, I would avoid reassigning `response` though.                                                          
            Use two appropriately named `const`s.

Answer (score -1):

`await` is very simple concept - it just makes your function wait for the Promise in synchronous manner. In order to make use of it, put `await` before any expression that returns a Promise. In your case, you can return `fetch()` in your `login()` function and then just:

```
await login(this.state.email, this.state.password);
// execution continued when fetch is done
```